# Can you play Diablo 3 multiplayer between PC and xbox

Tags: diablo-iii

Can I with Diablo 3 on the PC player with my friend Bob who has Diablo 3 on the xbox?

My understanding was that originally there were some major differences in some things like drop rates because of the real money auction house on the PC and not xbox but I was thinking that now they are more in line with each other that perhaps it would be feasible.

So is there any way to do this and if not have blizzard made a statement one way or the other on whether this will ever be possible.

For what its worth I'm assuming not but figured it would be silly not to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the forums on [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718652-diablo-iii/67093262), the answer is no.

A better source is [this article](http://www.polygon.com/2013/2/26/4031372/diablo-3-will-not-include-cross-platform-play-between-pc-and-ps3) which states the same. D3 was never designed for cross-platform multiplayer.

Here is [yet another article](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2013/02/diablo-3-for-ps3ps4-will-not-feature-cross-platform-multiplayer/) confirming that sad truth.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Microsoft refuses to allow cross-platform multiplayer. It's one of the main reasons Final Fantasy XIV didn't release on the Xbox 360/One.

Answer (score 2):

No, and it probably will never be cross-platform. They are, for almost 100% of the time, on different versions.